# Javascript - Inheriting and modifying an object

Tags: javascript, inheritance, var

I am trying to change a property of an object like this:

```
secondFunction = function()
{
    var bla = { 
    a:1, //properties
    };

    bla.localFunction = function(){
    a = 2; //can he read and modify this property?
    }

return bla; //return back object
}

firstFunction = function()
{
var testing = secondFunction(); //now testing is the object.
testing.localFunction(); //this is supposed to call localFunction and change the "a" property to 2
console.log(testing.a); //displays 1, not 2 as I thought it would
}

firstFunction();
```

I might be wrong(as I am new to javascript), but properties are global to the entire object, and as localFunction is a part of the object, I think it should be able to read property "a" and modify it to 2. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You are looking for the `this` keyword. `this` is not a block scope! Try to use `this.a = 2`. In essence, no, the variables declared in the block are not like 'local globals' - the `this` keyword will contain its 'scope'. Thats simplifying it a bit, but read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: I don't see any inheritance in here... Also, IIRC, `a` won't be a variable of `secondFunction`, but a global one, i.e. `console.log('a')` should print something.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach `a` is not a global here, `bla` is it's parent and bla is returned by the function, therefore assigned to the global `testing` var, therefore only `testing` is directly global. `a` is a variable of the `return` value of `secondFunction`.

Comment: `a` inside `bla.localFunction` is global. `a` inside `bla` is not.

Comment: Aah, I didn't see the `a:1` inside `bla`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a link to the `this` documentation on MDN, they do a much better job of explaining it than I could do here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Heres a working implementation of your function, the only difference is I used `document.write` so the snippet immediately spits out the response, which should be `12`.

```js
secondFunction = function()
{
    var bla = { 
        a:1,
    };

    bla.localFunction = function(){
        // Heres the magic: this is currently bound to your `bla` object inside this function!
        this.a = 2;
    }

    return bla;
}

firstFunction = function(){
    var testing = secondFunction();
    document.write(testing.a);
    testing.localFunction();
    document.write(testing.a);
}

firstFunction();
```

Heres a much more cleaned up version of the snippet:

```js
function secondFunction(){
  // Dont waste precious memory to store something you could do in one go!
  return { 
    a: 1,
    // Functions are first-class in JS, so you can simply use them as values
    localFunction: function(){
      this.a = 2;
    }
  };
}

function firstFunction(){
  var testing = secondFunction();
  document.write(testing.a);
  testing.localFunction();
  document.write(testing.a);
}

firstFunction();
```

Comment: Your example worked, but now I think I know how it'd work the way I wanted... I should have simply done: console.log(a); and that displays 2, no "this" needed. Now I am trying to figure out why...

Comment: Because when you set a variable without the `var` keyword, its scope is automatically global, but you want to _avoid_ setting global things as they consume needless amounts of memory. Try playing with `this` in objects and constructors, and make it a good friend. Try to avoid globals where possible, as they never get removed from memory since they are attached to your host object. The way I showed you above seems like a much safer way to store multiple instance with a key `a` in them as well.

Comment: "this" is confusing, but I just really figured out what I had to do, lol. bla.a = 2; would have changed the property a to 2 and not create a global var. Anyways thank you.

Comment: `this` is _not_ confusing and much safer. You will quickly run into issues the way you are referencing your objects. `bla.a = 2` only works in this specific case, and if you use my shortened, memory efficient code you will see that that does _not_ work anymore since I am not initiating a variable anymore, I am directly returning it, so the `this` keyword now has explicit meaning. Ah well, read up on Javascript and we'll discuss the merits of `this` in a couple of years :)